# C# COM implement enumerable without referencing MSCORLIB

Tags: c#, com

I am creating a COM interface which should allow to use `For Each` in Visual Basic Scripts and `IEnumVariant` in C++. The gotcha is that I don't want that the C++ client application needs to import mscorlib.tlb.

So far my interface is:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ICars : System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IEnumVARIANT
{
    int Count { get; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class Cars : ICars
{
    int ICars.Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

    int IEnumVARIANT.Next(int celt, object[] rgVar, IntPtr pceltFetched)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int IEnumVARIANT.Skip(int celt)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    int IEnumVARIANT.Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumVARIANT IEnumVARIANT.Clone()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

TlbExp spits out this code:

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: carsIEnumerator.tlb

[
     uuid(3BBCEAA2-9498-48BF-8053-1CEFB3C1C86F),
     version(1.0),
     custom(90883F05-3D28-11D2-8F17-00A0C9A6186D,  "ClassLibraryIEnumerator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")

 ]
 library ClassLibraryIEnumerator
 {
     // TLib :     // TLib : mscorlib.dll : {BED7F4EA-1A96-11D2-8F08-00A0C9A6186D}
importlib("mscorlib.tlb");
// TLib : OLE Automation : {00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
importlib("stdole2.tlb");

// Forward declare all types defined in this typelib
interface ICars;

[
  odl,
  uuid(ABD2A9E4-D5C5-3ED9-88AF-4C310BD5792D),
  version(1.0),
  dual,
  oleautomation,
  custom(0F21F359-AB84-41E8-9A78-36D110E6D2F9, "ClassLibraryIEnumerator.ICars")    

]
interface ICars : IDispatch {
    [id(0x60020000), propget]
    HRESULT Count([out, retval] long* pRetVal);
};
```

how can I avoid this?

Even if I just have my custom interface and a single class (without using any .NET type), the reference is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEnumVARIANT type declaration has to come from *somewhere*.  It is not a standard type like `int` that every compiler knows about.  If you author the IDL yourself then you'd use `#import "oaidl.idl"` to include the definition.  But that can't work in .NET since the type library exporter doesn't use IDL.  So it comes from a place that the exporter does know about, mscorlib.tlb

The workaround is to just put the interface declaration in your own code instead of using the one in mscorlib.  Copy/paste it from the [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/ComTypes/ienumvariant.cs,3b4f380e684d2b31) or this:

```
[Guid("00020404-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]   
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComImport]
public interface IEnumVARIANT
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int Next(int celt, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0), Out] object[] rgVar, IntPtr pceltFetched);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Skip(int celt);

    [PreserveSig]
    int Reset();

    IEnumVARIANT Clone();
}
```

And use YourNamespace.IEnumVARIANT in your ICars declaration.

---

Declaring your own enumerator interface type is a solution as well, IEnumVARIANT does not win any prizes.  You can drop the wonky methods nobody ever uses and you can make it type-safe.  An acceptable alternative if you control the client code as well or don't have to keep a `foreach` in a scripting language happy.  Consider:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICarEnumerator {
    ICar Next();
}
```

And `ICarEnumerator GetCars()` in the ICars interface.

---

Last, but not least, consider to not implement an iterator at all.  Just make it look like an array in the client code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICars
{
    int Count { get; }
    ICar this[int index] { get; }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, as always. I was going towards the second option you suggested (i.e. Count + this[int index]). However, if I implement the ICarEnumerator, then should I be able to use it both in C++ and in VBscript right?

Comment: Yes.  A VBScript programmer is however apt to expect `For Each` to work.

Comment: I implemented the `ICarEnumerator` and when I call `For Each car in cars.GetCars()` VBscript says:  Object doesn't support this property or method. Any idea?

Comment: As noted in the answer and my previous comment, foreach in a scripting language requires IEnumVARIANT.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood!

Comment: BTW, how can I use the operator [i] from VBscript? I can't find a way. I tried cars[i], cars(i), cars.Item[i]

Comment: Use array syntax, Cars(ix).  Please click the Ask Question when you have more questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141734/discussion-between-peval27-and-hans-passant).

Comment: I have asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43414901/how-to-use-vb-script-array-syntax-for-custom-com-interface)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue/need , and I found this good article.

https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/exposing-an-enumerator-from-managed-code-to-com/

Answer (score 0):

“The gotcha is that I don't want that the C++ client application needs to import mscorlib.tlb.”

That is impossible, since you are creating your COM coclass with .NET which automatically brings mscorlib.tlb and mscoree.dll into the play. Try it out with a simple object that can only add two integers.

As Hans Passant pointed out, you don’t need the interface `IEnumVARIANT` at all. Any COM collection must be based on a C# collection, for example `List<T>`. This C# collection has a method `GetEnumeration()` that spits out an `IEnumeration` object serving as `IEnumVARIANT` in COM. All you have to do is include `IEnumerator GetEnumerator();` in the interface and delegate the implementation to the `GetEnumeration()` method of the C# collection.

I show this in a complete example. Consider a Bank coclass that manages a collection of accounts. I need coclasses for the Bank, Account and the collection of AllAccounts.

I start with the crucial coclass AllAccounts:

```
//AllAccounts.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BankServerCSharp
{
  [ComVisible(true)]  // This is mandatory.
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
  public interface IAllAccounts
  {
    int Count{ get; }

    [DispId(0)]
    IAccount Item(int i);

    [DispId(-4)]
    IEnumerator GetEnumerator();

    Account AddAccount();

    void RemoveAccount(int i);

    void ClearAllAccounts();
  }

  [ComVisible(true)]  // This is mandatory.
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class AllAccounts:IAllAccounts 
  {
    private AllAccounts(){ } // private constructor, coclass noncreatable
    private List<IAccount> Al = new List<IAccount>();
    public static AllAccounts MakeAllAccounts() { return new AllAccounts(); }
    //public, but not exposed to COM

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return Al.GetEnumerator();  }

    public int Count { get { return Al.Count; } }

    public IAccount Item(int i)  { return (IAccount)Al[i - 1];  }

    public Account AddAccount() { Account acc = Account.MakeAccount();
                                        Al.Add(acc); return acc; }

    public void RemoveAccount(int i) {  Al.RemoveAt(i - 1);  }

    public void ClearAllAccounts() { Al.Clear(); }

  }
}
```

The `DispId` values of 0 and -4 are required for the default `Item` method and for the `GetEnumerator()` method. The two other files are:

```
Account.cs:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BankServerCSharp
{
  [ComVisible(true)]  // This is mandatory.
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
  public interface IAccount
  {
    double Balance { get; } // A property
    void Deposit(double b); // A method
  }

  [ComVisible(true)]  // This is mandatory.
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class Account:IAccount
  {
    private double mBalance = 0;
    private Account() { }     // private constructor, coclass noncreatable

    public static Account MakeAccount() { return new Account(); }
    //MakeAccount is not exposed to COM, but can be used by other classes

    public double Balance  { get {  return mBalance; } }
    public void Deposit(double b) { mBalance += b; }
  }
}

Bank.cs:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace BankServerCSharp
{
  [ComVisible(true)]  // This is mandatory.
  [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
  public interface IBank { IAllAccounts Accounts { get; }  }

  [ComVisible(true)]  // This is mandatory.
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
  public class Bank:IBank
  {
    private readonly AllAccounts All;
    public Bank() {  All = AllAccounts.MakeAllAccounts(); } 
    public IAllAccounts Accounts {  get { return All; } }
  }
}
```

You must register the server with the x64 version of Regasm.

A test of the server with C++:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#import  "D:\Aktuell\CSharpProjects\BankServerCSharp\BankServerCSharp\bin\Release\BankServerCSharp.tlb"
//this is the path of my C# project's bin\Release folder
inline void TESTHR(HRESULT x) { if FAILED(x) _com_issue_errorex(x, nullptr, ID_NULL);}
int main()
{
  try
  {
    TESTHR(CoInitialize(0));
    BankServerCSharp::IBankPtr BankPtr = nullptr;
    TESTHR(BankPtr.CreateInstance("BankServerCSharp.Bank"));
    BankServerCSharp::IAllAccountsPtr AllPtr = BankPtr->Accounts;
    BankServerCSharp::IAccountPtr FirstAccountPtr = AllPtr->AddAccount();
    TESTHR(FirstAccountPtr->Deposit(47.11));
    AllPtr->AddAccount();
    TESTHR(AllPtr->Item[2]->Deposit(4711));

    CStringW out, add;
    for (int i = 1; i <= AllPtr->Count; i++)
    {
      add.Format(L"Balance of account %d: %.2f.\n", i, AllPtr->Item[i]->Balance);
      out += add;
    }

    out += L"\n";
    AllPtr->RemoveAccount(1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= AllPtr->Count; i++)
    {
      add.Format(L"Balance of account %d: %.2f.\n", i, AllPtr->Item[i]->Balance);
      out += add;
    }

    AllPtr->ClearAllAccounts();
    add.Format(L"Number of accounts: %ld.\n", AllPtr->Count);
    out += L"\n" + add;
    MessageBoxW(NULL, out, L"Result", MB_OK);

    //Raise an exception:
    AllPtr->RemoveAccount(1);
  }
  catch (const _com_error& e)
  {
    MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Oops! Index out of range!", L"Error", MB_OK);
  }
  CoUninitialize();// Uninitialize COM
  return 0;
}
```

Remark: `Item` is a vector in C++. I have no idea how to change it to the usual functional form, i.e. `Item(i)` instead of `Item[i]`.

In VBA, you can use the beloved `For Each` loop:

```
Sub CSharpBankTest()
 On Error GoTo Oops

  Dim Out As String
  Dim Bank As New BankServerCSharp.Bank            'New!

  Dim AllAccounts As BankServerCSharp.AllAccounts  'No New!
  Set AllAccounts = Bank.Accounts

  Dim AccountOne As BankServerCSharp.Account       'No New
  Set AccountOne = AllAccounts.AddAccount
  AccountOne.Deposit 47.11

  AllAccounts.AddAccount
  AllAccounts(2).Deposit 4711

  Dim i As Long
  Dim ac As BankServerCSharp.Account
  For Each ac In AllAccounts
    i = i + 1
    Out = Out & "Balance of account " & i & ": " & ac.Balance & vbNewLine
  Next
  Exit Sub
Oops:
  MsgBox "Error Message : " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"
End Sub
```